# vue.js - v-html alternative

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I come from a react background with JSX, so using something like

`var test = <div>i am a div</div>`

to set the html of some things is pretty common. I know you can achieve the same thing using v-html, but was wondering if it was the best/safest way to do so given my following code:

vue component

```
<template src="./templates/General.html"></template>

<script>
  export default {
      name: 'guide-general',
      data: function() {
          return {
              guides: [
                  {
                      title: "first",
                      description: "First description"
                  },
                  {
                      title: "second",
                      description: "second description"
                  },
                  {
                      title: "third",
                      description: `<ul>
                        <li>
                            test
                        </li>
                      </ul>`
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
      methods: {

      }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

html template

```
<article>
    <div v-for="guide in guides">
        <h4>{{ guide.title }}</h4>
        <div v-html="guide.description">
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include the ability to have HTML rendered from a vue property, you're going to need to use `v-html`. If you're allowing users to modify the property that the HTML may come from, then you're going to run into security concerns with XSS vulnerabilities, in which case you'll need to sanitize your inputs when the data is sent back to the server (I highly encourage you to use a reputable external library for this). If users won't be modifying your data, then there should be no safety concerns with using `v-html` at all.

Whenever you allow users to modify data of any kind, you open yourself up to potential security issues. You'll just need to anticipate what those issues are and work around them.

---

**June 2021 Update**

To clarify a point, if you don't need dynamic HTML rendering and only need to handle a conditional case for rendering certain predetermined HTML templates, then you can simply include conditional rendering in your Vue template. An example may look like this:

```html
<script>
    export default {
      name: 'guide-general',
      data: function() {
          return {
              guides: [
                  {
                      title: "first",
                      description: "First description",
                      as_list: false
                  },
                  {
                      title: "second",
                      description: "second description",
                      as_list: false
                  },
                  {
                      title: "third",
                      description: "test",
                      as_list: true
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
      methods: {

      }
  }
</script>

<article>
    <div v-for="guide in guides">
        <h4>{{ guide.title }}</h4>
        <div v-if="guide.as_list">
            <ul>
                <li>{{guide.description}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div v-else>{{guide.description}}</div>
    </div>
</article>
```

In short, if you don't need *dynamic* HTML rendering and only need *conditional* HTML rendering, then use `v-if` where applicable and structure your data to allow for conditional rendering to function correctly. Otherwise use `v-html`, or possibly even structure JSON data to recursively generate predefined components using `<component :is="component.name">` (this is fairly complicated, so I will not be going into detail in this answer).

Comment: I tried to use the `{{ variableHere }}` but it printed the html actual tags instead of converting them

Comment: @Pete Please note that my answer does not include information about how to handle input that contains HTML tags as part of the string data. Also note that the question itself is not asking how to accomplish this, but is instead asking about best practices. Finally, note that the question already shows how to convert the string HTML data into actual HTML via the `v-html` attribute, e.g. by doing `<div v-html="variableHere"></div>`. Moustache syntax, i.e. `{{variableHere}}`, will NOT treat the data as actual HTML and will instead treat it as plain text.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody looking a way to render hmtl restricted to a set of tags, a solution is to parse the html string and use [render functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html) to programmatically build the template. With this approach you can create your own safe html renderer and avoid the use of `v-html` and external libraries. Here is a small sample of how such html view component could look like:

***HtmlView.vue***

```
<script>

import { h } from "vue";

export default {
  props: {
    html: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    tags: {
      /** @type {import("vue").PropType<String[]>} */
      type: Array,
      default: () => ["b"]
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const html = parseHTML(props.html);

    // return the render function
    return () => {
      const output = [];
      html.childNodes.forEach(childNode => {
        output.push(renderNode(childNode, props.tags));
      });
      if (output.length == 1) {
        return output[0];
      } else if (output.length == 0) {
        return "";
      }
      return output;
    };
  }
};

const parseHTML = (html) => {
  var template = document.createElement("template");
  template.innerHTML = html;
  return template.content;
};

/**
 *
 * @param {Node} node
 * @param {String[]} tags
 */
const renderNode = (node, tags) => {
  const nodeType = node.nodeType;
  if (nodeType == 1) {
    const nodeName = node.nodeName.toLocaleLowerCase();
    if (tags.includes(nodeName)) {
      const children = [];
      node.childNodes.forEach(childNode => {
        children.push(renderNode(childNode, tags));
      });
      return h(nodeName, children);
    }
  }
  return node.textContent;
};

</script>
```

The `tags` property of the component limits the set of supported tags. In this example, by default, only the `<b>` tag is supported.

Note that the sample above will only render [DOM Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) of type 1 (`ELEMENT_NODE`) and will also omit any attributes of the node, but it can be easily extended to support attributes is required.

I created a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-frog-q4xjhs).